# Regular Expression - Get Characters in Between Quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string.  What reg ex can I use to grab only the email address or whatever appears between the double quotation marks?

```
'E11000 duplicate key error index: app-dev.users.$email_1  dup key: { : "testuse@example.net" }'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/"([^"]+)"/
```

**TESTING:**

```
s='E11000 duplicate key error index: app-dev.users.$email_1  dup key: { : "testuse@example.net" }';
var email = s.match(/"([^"]+)"/)[1];
//=> testuse@example.net
```